# XAMPP SSL connection timed out

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, web, https, xampp

I am trying to run an already developed website on my XAMPP localhost. However, whenever I type in

```
localhost/myFolderNameInHTDOCS
```

the URL gets rewritten to

```
https://localhost/myFolderNameInHTDOCS
```

and it tries to eastablish a secure connection.

After a while the connection gets timed out. 
I guess this is an SSL issue. I have never worked with it before. Any changes I need to make in XAMPP configiration files, maybe htaccess???

Comment: By default XAMPP does not support SSL. You will either need to use a self-signed certificate and enable SSL or just remove the https redirect on your dev box.

Comment: An SSL cerificate has already been bought, I need to figure out a way to simply enable SSL on my XAMPP localhost server

Comment: the SSL certificate for your remote domain is no good on `localhost`. When the domains mismatch, your browser will throw an error anyway.

Comment: Could you help me with a link that will help me with the steps to your solution.

Comment: There is probably a http to https rewrite rule in your .htaccess file, I'd just remove that on your dev box.